# How to convert a csv set of columns into a json array?

Tags: javascript, php, json, csv

I need to upload a large dataset in excel to a database. I tried some online CSV to JSON converters, but one of my excel columns needs to be an array. When I convert it to json I get double quoutes or backticks inside the array. How can I escape the first quotation marks or what can i do?

See below the difference between what i expect and what i get after converting

Column structure:
 Name       - project        - experience
 John doe - Project star - [“item 1”, “item 2”, “item 3”]

```
"20": {
 "name": "John Doe",
 "project": "Project star",
 "experience": ["item 1","item 2", "item3"] //What I expect
 "experience": "[“item 1”,”item 2”, “item3”]" //What I get
 },
```

Comment: you can use a regexp to replace the quotes with real quotes, then JSON.parse() the result.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Could you me more specific please? Set an example maybe?

Comment: Show input data example. Can you use tabs instead commas as separator?